# WFS not working in Openlayers, working in qgis. WMS working ok

Tags: openlayers, wfs

If I try to import data from WFS service https://mrdata.usgs.gov/services/ca? into qGIS, it is working normally. But when I try to make html/js file on local machine using WFS service functionallity, I have no success. I got WMS to work using ol.

This is the code I used:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>WFS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.4/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.4/build/ol.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script>
    <!-- looks like something is loading, based on network transfer -->
      var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new ol.format.WFS({
          gmlFormat: new ol.format.GML({
            srsName: 'Nothing'})
        }),
        url: 'https://mrdata.usgs.gov/services/ca?version=1.1.0&maxfeatures=50&SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=lith-low'
      });
    <!-- url: 'https://mrdata.usgs.gov/services/ca?version=1.1.0&maxfeatures=20&SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=lith-low&SRSNAME=EPSG:4326&BBOX=-132.04568113772455717,26.46616766467064963,-101.50074101796406012,47.67616766467065759', -->
    <!-- strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox //default ol.loadingstrategy.all -->



      var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: vectorSource,
        style: new ol.style.Style({
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: null,
            width: 5
          })
        })
      });

      var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      });

  var map = new ol.Map({
         layers: [raster, vector],
        target: document.getElementById('map'),
        view: new ol.View({
          center: [-13000233,3901982],
          maxZoom: 19,
          zoom: 10
        })
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Does anyone have any idea what is the problem here?

---

updated

I've tried it with XMLHttpRequest object, different url and still no success.

Is it possible that GML from the site is not in the correct structure or am I missing something in the readFeatures block of code.

Here is my block of code, if I try it this way, the result is couple of features near crossover of Greenwich and equator, if I try with different projection (uncomment projection key in view), the result is couple of features at south pole, if I try with uncommented readFeatures block, I get no visual result of features, just osm map.

```
<script>

//var taURL = 'https://mrdata.usgs.gov/services/ca?version=1.1.0&maxfeatures=50&SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=lith-low&SRSNAME=EPSG:4326';
var taURL = 'https://mrdata.usgs.gov/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/mnt/mrt/map-files/ca.map&service=wfs&version=1.0.0&request=getfeature&TYPENAME=lith-low&maxfeatures=5';
var imageExtent = [-122.960350,32.553815 -116.215897,42.008882];
//var imageExtent = [-123.729652,32.553815 -114.783885,42.008882]; //drugi link
window.onload = function(){
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200) {
            var xmlDoc = xhr.responseXML;
            //console.log(xhr.responseText);
            //console.log(xmlDoc);

            var gmlFormat = new ol.format.GML2();

            var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
                source: new ol.source.Vector({
                    format: gmlFormat
                    ,url: taURL,
                  }),
                style: new ol.style.Style({
                  stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: [255,0,0, 1],
                    width: 2
                  })
                })
              });

            //still not working  
            //var features = gmlFormat.readFeatures(xmlDoc,{
            //  featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857',
            //  dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326'
            //}); 
            //vector.getSource().addFeatures(features);

            var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.OSM()
              });

            var map = new ol.Map({
                //layers: [raster, vector],
                layers: [raster],
                target: 'map',
                view: new ol.View({
                    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
                    center: [0,0],
                    //center: ol.extent.getCenter(imageExtent),
                    maxZoom: 30,
                    zoom: 2
                })
            });
            map.addLayer(vector);
        }
    };
    xhr.open("GET",taURL,true);
    xhr.send();
};
</script>
```

Comment: You have conflicting versions params in your request

Comment: `srsName: 'Nothing'` looks wrong too.

Comment: probable duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/239445/openlayers-3-wfs-gml2-layer-wrong-projection-and-displaying-on-wrong-location

Comment: Your version=1.1.0&... VERSION=1.0.0& request is generating a version 1.0.0 response, Also note that the advertised location for the GetFeature request is https://mrdata.usgs.gov/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/mnt/mrt/map-files/ca.map& and not as you have it

Answer (score 1):

Let's make a list of issues:

- Code below in first sample is false for two reasons: `srsName: 'Nothing'` is invalid & `gmlFormat` should be `ol.format.GML2` if using WFS 1.0.0

  ```
  new ol.format.WFS({
    gmlFormat: new ol.format.GML({
      srsName: 'Nothing'})
  }),
  ```
- There was an issue with `color: null` in your first sample

  ```
  new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: null,
      width: 5
  })
  ```
- `new ol.format.GML2()` should be `new ol.format.WFS()`
- The biggest issue but not simple to grasp: you are using WFS 1.0.0 in your call to the webservice. Implicitly, it means GML format would be 2.1.2 whereas default in OpenLayers is 3.1.1. I choose to use WFS 1.1.0 to simplify and because I had some issues with WFS 1.0.0.

You will find [a working demo](https://bl.ocks.org/ThomasG77/0142b639a3626c427ba09f7db7f8ecb3) fixing your issues. I also choose to use `fetch` instead of `XMLHttpRequest` (both are fine)